# When I run this JavaScript code in Visual Studio Code, some console.log() operations work but some don't

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-objects, console.log

I am working on a JavaScript objects exercise for a course I'm following, but when I run the code I don't get the expected result. I've cut the code down to the essentials for clarity.

```
const myObject = {
    _array: [ 
        {item: 'a', item2: 'b', item3: 'c'},
        {item: 'd', item2: 'e', item3: 'f'},
        {item: 'g', item2: 'h', item3: 'i'}
        ],

    get items () {
        return this._array;
    },

    addThing (newItem1, newItem2, newItem3) {
        let thing = {
            item1: newItem1,
            item2: newItem2,
            item3: newItem3
        };
        /* `this.players.push(player);` is adding a new player object to the `_players` array of the `team` object. It uses the `push()` method to add the `player` object to the array. */
        this._array.push(thing);
      }

}
console.log('hello before');
myObject.addThing('j', 'k', 'l');
console.log(myObject._array);
console.log('hello after');
```

Running this from a terminal window gives me the expected result where the array is dumped however the screen capture below is what I expect to acheive with F5/'Run and Debug' ...

[image: Terminal capture]

...  running it with F5 or Run and Debug gives me what's below though, where there is only placeholder ...s for the array output.

[image: Debug console capture]

I'd like to understand why there is no output of _array when run this way.

Comment: But the array **is** logged, right there in the second line of the output?

Comment: I'm expecting to see 
    "[ { item: 'a', item2: " 
etc from running F5/'Run and Debug' instead of
    (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 
etc.
I've edited the main post to make my question clearer.

Comment: Well the debugger console allows you do inspect the object values interactively - click on the arrays and objects to expand them! (although the error message in your screenshot would suggest that you only clicked after the program did finish running - if you don't actually want to interactively debug, don't use the debug console but the terminal).

Comment: Thanks for the input. This question was more about understanding what was causing the problem and (potentially) rectifying it than finding ways around it.

Answer (score 1):

Console methods (like `console.log`) accept different values as parameters.

A typical usage is with strings. In such a case, the console displays the exact message:

```
< console.log('message');
> message
```

In case of more complex values, the exact display depends on the console.

In your case, you are trying to display an array of objects.

One console displays it in full, while the other console displays a short version (with ellipsis in place of objects' content).

Chrome, for example behaves like so:

```
< console.log([1,2,3,4], 'some', 'other', 'value');
>  (4) [1,2,3,4] 'some' 'other' 'value'
```

*(note the display of the array prefixed with the number of entries, which is not valid json, and also that the strings are now surrounded with quotes)*

Keep also in mind that in javascript, console methods are not the same as STDOUT/STDERR. It is just a coincidence or convenience that sometimes console.log also shows up in the STDOUT/STDERR, as you saw in the 1st screenshot.

In other words, if you want more control on the output, you'd need to do two distinct things:

1. use the proper output mechanism (e.g. [`process.stdout`, in nodejs](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-stdout-stdin-stderr-node-js/))
2. terminal output is just a string/stream, so you need to serialize the complex values. An easy example is with `JSON.stringify()`.

---

**TL:DR;** if you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject._array))`, the value will *probably* show up in-full in both cases (but it will lack fancy highlighting etc).

Comment: Indeed! 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject._array))
produced
"[{"item":"a","item2":"b","item3":"c"},{"item":"d","item2":"e","item3":"f"},{"item":"g","item2":"h","item3":"i"},{"item1":"j","item2":"k","item3":"l"}]"
Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have just discovered that replacing

```
console.log(myObject._array);
```

with

```
console.table(myObject._array);
```

solved this issue. Apparently "the console displays "{…}" as a placeholder rather than expanding and displaying each object's complete contents to avoid cluttering the console output with extensive data."

The output now looks like this: -

[image: Debug console output with table]